Nextjs - how to use SSR with a 'use client' global nav bar?
I'm new to nextjs and I'm struggling to figure out how to organize my project. I have a nav bar that is global for the site, and I use useState() to determine which tab is selected at the moment. Picture something like the instagram nav bar with home, search, etc..
My initial idea is to put this nav bar in the root layout (using app router btw). But since this adds 'use client' to the root, everything below it cannot be rendered on the server right? Which seems like it basically defeats the point of nextjs.
So my second idea was to add my nav bar individually to every single page, essentially add the nav bar at the leaves instead of the root. But this feels really clunky as I have say 10+ pages you can visit, and I have the same component at the bottom of all of them. Is this the best way anyways though, or what would be a common way to go about this?

You can extract navbar as an independent component, and import it in server component like root layout, allows you keep your rendering strategy.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#moving-client-components-down-the-tree

Exactly what I needed, ty. If you make it an answer I'll mark it

On a side note, Server component is not the same as SSR

okay I repost it again as answer, thanks.

You can extract navbar as an independent component, and import it in server component like root layout, allows you keep your rendering strategy.
reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#moving-client-components-down-the-tree
